# .ssh/known-host file setup when using tunneling

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I have a script called `tnl` I use to help \ setup and use tunneling via ssh. It automatically configures the gateway and then figures out what ports should be used by my program. In my configuration file, I may have:

```
gateway: -system dmgwy01 -start 2000 -background
system:  -system foo01
system:  -system foo02
system:  -system foo03
```

When I run the command:

```
$ tnl start dmgwy01
```

This will start my tunneling with the following ports:

```
 ssh -N -c 3des dmgwy01 -L 2000/foo01/22 -L 2001/foo02/22 -L 2002/foo03/22
```

Note that I don't have to assign ports to the individual systems. This is done automatically by my script.

Now, I can start a tunnel by doing:

```
$ tnl ssh foo01
```

It works great. That is until I change my configuration file and add a new system:

```
gateway: -system dmgwy01 -start 2000 -background
system:  -system bar01
system:  -system foo01
system:  -system foo02
system:  -system foo03
```

Now, the tunneling starts like this:

```
 ssh -N -c 3des dmgwy01 -L 2000/bar01/22 -L 2001/foo01/22 -L 2002/foo02/22 -L 2003/foo03/22
```

Note that the port numbering for the various systems have changed. That's fine, I really don't care about the actual port numbers. However, now when I use the tunnel I get:

```
$ tnl ssh bar01               
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx...
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts:1
RSA host key for [localhost]:2000 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I've traced this to my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. When I had my original setup, the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` was setup this way:

```
[localhost]:2000 ssh-rsa (Fingerprint for f0001)
[localhost]:2001 ssh-rsa (Fingerprint for foo02)
[localhost]:2002 ssh-rsa (Fingerprint for f0003)
```

Now, `[localhost]:2000` is `bar01` and not `foo01`, so of course their fingerprints differ. I'll also have the same issue trying to get on `foo01` or `foo02` because their port numbers have changed, and their fingerprints won't match either.

Is there a way to get around this issue? Is it possible to force my `.known_hosts` to use system names instead of port numbers? Is it possible to somehow add a *note* to my `.known_hosts` file that will map host to hostname, and allow me to remap the host names to there previous ports if possible?

I can get around this by turning off `StrictHostKeyChecking`, but that doesn't necessarily fix the issue. I can simply edit my `known_hosts` when I change the configuration and recalculate the host keys, but I'm trying to keep things simple.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your script `tnl` already sort out a mapping between the local port number and the name of the host to forward to. It is not just a small step to modify the `known_hosts` file so that the same local port maps to the same host - each line in `known_hosts` contains this information.

Comment: I was thinking of using the `known_hosts` to help with the port mapping. If `foo01` was mapped to port 2002, I'll remap it that way even after the system configuration was changed. However, `known_hosts` doesn't contain any system name -- just port mappings. I merely see `[localhost]:2002` and a fingerprint of the host. There's no way to know if that was `foo02` or `foo01`. Can I add a comment to the `known_host` file and embed the machine name or IP address?